# Javascript is not working for a color game

Tags: javascript

I have made a color game app but my javascript is not working fine and always alerts me with wrong. Please help me rectify this code. Thanks

```
var colors = [
    "rgb(255,0,0)",
    "rgb(255,255,0)",
    "rgb(0,255,0)",
    "rgb(0,255,255)",
    "rgb(0,0,255)",
    "rgb(255,0,255)"
]
var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var pickedColor = colors[3];
var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");

colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++){
    // add initial color to square
    squares[i].style.background = colors[i];

    // add click listeners to squares
    squares[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        var clickedColor = this.style.background;
        if(clickedColor == pickedColor){
            alert("CORRECT");
        } else {
            alert("WRONG");
        }
    });


}
```

It always alerts "Wrong" and can't pick the right one.

Comment: Please create snippet for code

Comment: Could you please provide your HTML code ? Then we could test your code in same condition.

Comment: Please post the relevant markup as well and preferably make a working snippet for a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  to demonstrate the issue

Comment: check in debugger mode or do console.log(clickedColor) console.log(pickedColor) , might be both are not matching even though they are with same "meaning".

Answer (score 1):

When you apply style on element, style is normalized. RGB color is normalized with adding of spaces after commas. You need to added spaces to your array.

`var colors = [
    "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
    "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
    "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
    "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
    "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
    "rgb(255, 0, 255)"
]`

P.S. Here's my advice - learn how to debug using dev tools. Otherwise you'll face difficulties trying to develop something more sophisticated.

Comment: Dear Sir!, thanks and from where i can learn to use dev tools?

Comment: @ImranAhmed https://www.google.ie/search?q=how+to+use+dev+tools&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIE751IE751&oq=how+to+use+dev+tools&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.9076j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Thanks a lot. Adding spaces between colors has solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

As @timbset outlined, `"rgb(0, 255, 255)" is not equal to "rgb(0,255,255)"`.

Below is an excerpt from a fiddle that uses a function to compare the R, G and B values directly instead of comparing the entire RGB string (that may or may not be normalized).

```
if (compareColors(clickedColor, pickedColor)) {
    alert("CORRECT");
} else {
    alert("WRONG");
}

...

function compareColors (a, b) {
  return (
    getRGBfromString(a)[0] === getRGBfromString(b)[0] &&
    getRGBfromString(a)[1] === getRGBfromString(b)[1] &&
    getRGBfromString(a)[2] === getRGBfromString(b)[2]
   )
}

function getRGBfromString (rgb) {
  return rgb.substring(4, rgb.length - 1).replace(/ /g, '').split(',')
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mue1wfdm/

Comment: Thanks and spaces between RGB colors have solved my issue. Again thanks a lot.